# python docx стиль параграфа

Tags: python

Требуется взять конкретный параграф из одного файла и перенести его в другой файл. В общем-то, ничего сложного и все получается. НО. Не переносится стиль параграфа. Вот изображение. на нем видно что стили не совпадают. 
Код переноса

```
import os, codecs, docx
filename = docx.Document('ACD.docx')
print filename.paragraphs[0].text
print filename.paragraphs[0].style
filename2 = docx.Document()
filename2.add_paragraph(text=filename.paragraphs[0].text,style=filename.paragraphs[0].style)
filename2.save('a.docx')
```

[image: Результат]

Пробовал вставлять и в исходный документ (бытует мнение что docx не работает со стилем которого ранее не было) - стиль не сохраняется.
Просьба:
1. не предлагать добавить стиль руками - в дальнейшем количество параграфов будет миллион и все они разные. А форматирование должно быть сохранено
2. Не предлагать банально скопировать из одного файла в другой - естественно при переносе текста из одного файла в другой с ним буду происходить трансформации

Answer (score 0):

Я не работал на python2, но на python3 для переноса стилей используйте:

```
import docx
doc1 = docx.Document('example.docx')
doc2 = docx.Document('restyled.docx')

# получаем из первого документа стили всех абзацев
styles = []
for paragraph in doc1.paragraphs:
    styles.append(paragraph.style)

# применяем стили ко всем абзацам второго документа
for i in range(len(doc2.paragraphs)):
    doc2.paragraphs[i].style = styles[i]

doc2.save('restored.docx')
```